# multiple files from different directory as input to awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have different files with same file names and they are stored in different directories such as

```
/path/to/2000/{a,b,c}.txt ... /path/to/2001/{a,b,c}.txt
```

since I want to use variables to represent the directories like

```
/path/to/{1998..2013}/{a.b.c}.txt
```

and how can I parametrize the directory name to input  like

```
awk '....' /path/to/{$start..$end}/{a,b,c}.txt
```

please be noted that I cannot loop all directories to input file one by one to the awk since the awk script needs all information from those files at the same time. thx for helping.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `..` operator requires the paramters to be literals, not variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval:

```
eval awk '...' /path/to/{$start..$end}/{a,b,c}.txt
```

Or find and xargs, but it is not as accurate:

```
find /path/to -path '*/[21][90][09][0-9]/[abc].txt' | xargs awk '....'
```